# How to fix size of autocomplete with multiple true

Tags: jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I am using `Primeface 3.5`(`autocomplete` with `mutiple` `true`) and `JSF`. 
[image]

Here i need to fix the size of the `autocomplete` `text box` depending upon the member.
Please suggest me how to achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS? If yes, what was the problem?

Comment: No, i want to take the fix input 2 0r 3 or 5...